# How to view the source, or worksheets, in an XLSM so that it looks like just a regular Excel document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I just received an XLSM file from my boss.

It's a nifty little program and all. But what I'm looking for is to see all the worksheets involved; specifically, locations where dropdown boxes are populated from.

I've never actually seen or used an XLSM, and perhaps I'm not asking the right question. But, is there a way to open this so that it looks like just a regular Excel document?

Comment: you'll want to view the vba or `visual basic` through enabling the `developer tab`

Comment: you can also install the [explode formula auditing](http://www.cornerstoneresults.com/RefLib/KnlgeBk/mso_ms_excel_formula_auditing_plug_in.htm) add-in to explode formulas

Comment: Holding down shift while opening most office documents stops automatic macros from running. Often code has been put in these macros to hide various elements etc.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Thank you. Looking through that, I was able to find what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the `developer tab` in excel options. On the left side of the developer tab is `visual basic` click on that you see all the sheets, modules, etc within the workbook, and what they're doing.

Answer (score 10):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

This works in every Office application and does show the VBA editor/code.